# Rest api for android ,php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<script src="../js/jquery2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var userid="" ;
    var username="";
    var usermobile="";
    var useremail="";
    var password="";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'insertuserdata.php',
            data:{'userid':userid,'username':username,'usermobile':usermobile,'useremail':useremail,'password':password},
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to create API for Android and using ajax here I want to pass values in my script variables in userid, username, useremail and password from the android. But I don't how to pass values to script using android. If anybody knows about please help me.

Comment: Where do these values userid,username,useremail and password come from?

Comment: Are you building an API for android that uses Ajax? That sounds...  wrong.

Comment: why you need to pass that data to script, if you are using API then you need to pass the data directly to the API right?

Comment: thankyou for help me but I already got my solution